# How to pass two strings as parameters into a C++ template template function

Tags: c++, string, templates

Following is the template function I am using

```
// Function to calculate bionomial coefficient.  
template <typename TYPE>
int C(TYPE &n, TYPE &k) {    

    if (!parametersChecking(n, k)) {
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return claculateBC(n,k);
    }

}
```

I am passing two string parameter to the function. But it says

> error: cannot convert ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string}’ to  ‘int’ for argument '1' to 'int calculateBC(int, int)'

But works fine if I pass `int` and `float` type parameters. I have tried stringstream, it does help only if the both the parameters are some text, but if one is text and another is number then it doesn't return desired result.

Passing the value from another function i.e.

```
void test3_string(int testNo) {

    std::string n = "john"; std::string k = "doe";
    int pass = 0;


//  std::stringstream ss(n);
//  ss >> tempN;
//  std::cout << tempN << std::endl;

//  std::stringstream ss2(k);
//  ss2 >> tempK;
//  std::cout << tempK << std::endl;    
    pass = C(n, k);
    printStatus(pass, testNo-1);
}
```

So can anyone please help how can I pass string to the function?

**Additional Info:**

```
int claculateBC(int n, int k){

    int bionomial_coefficient = 1;

    if (n == k || k == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    int nMinusK = n - k;    
    n = eachValuesFactorial(n);
    k = eachValuesFactorial(k);
    nMinusK = eachValuesFactorial(nMinusK);

    bionomial_coefficient = n / (k * nMinusK);

    return bionomial_coefficient;
}
```

Here is the full program if anyone wants to have a look: [Bionomial-Coefficient](http://repl.it/ivw/4)

Comment: Why are you even using a template?  Its seems like a simple overload would do what you want and be simpler...

Comment: THAT'S STRANGE! WHY DOWNVOTE FOR THE QUESTION!!!???

Comment: @ChrisDodd That's a good option. Didn't came in mind initially. I'll implement this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`calculateBC()` only accepts `int` values as input and performs arithmetic operations on them.  However, the `TYPE` of `C()` is `std::string`, not `int`.  So you need to convert the string values to integer values before you can call `calculateBC()`, eg:

```
// Function to calculate bionomial coefficient.  
template <typename TYPE>
int C(TYPE &n, TYPE &k) {    
    //...
}

// specialized Function for string parameters.
template <>
int C<std::string>(std::string &n, std::string &k) {
    int i_n = std::atoi(n.c_str());
    int i_k = std::atoi(k.c_str());
    // validate as needed...
    return C(i_n, i_k);
}
```

Comment: A template here seems like overkill -- just define two overloaded versions of  `C` (one with ints and one with strings).

Comment: @ChrisDodd reason of making `C` template is because calling `C` can be in various ways such as `C(int, int), C(float, float), C(string, string)`. As I mentioned in the problem works fine for other input except `string` therefore I think template would be handy as @RemyLebeau proposed.

Comment: @johnshumon: That doesn't require a template, it just requires overloading.  In fact, a template just gets in the way.

Answer (score 0):

Your templated function calls `calculateBC`, which only accepts `int`s. You need to make `calculateBC` a template function as well.  It only works with `float` and `int` because an implict conversion from `float` to `int` happens.

Alternatively, you could rethink your structure here, whether it means converting to `ints` inside `C()`, or even before calling `C()` and removing the template.

Comment: `calculateBC()` performs arithmetic operations on its input values, so it does not make sense to make it a template function, especially since the `TYPE` of `C()` is `std::string`.

Comment: if it doesn't make sense to template `calculateBC()` so it can be called with `strings`, it doesn't make sense to call `C()` with `strings` as the template parameter.

Comment: That depends on where the input is coming from.  For example, if the input is coming from a UI, it would make sense to pass strings.  You just have to convert them first before calculating.

Comment: sure, good point.  I'll edit my answer a bit.  I didn't take a super close look the first time through because I was on mobile.